# Configure Django to use a certain database only for write queries

Tags: python, django, django-database, django-orm

We have this open source app we built with Django http://map.ninux.org/ which is used by our wireless community network and is hosted outside of our network with Hetzner in Nurimberg.

We'd like to have a mirror inside our network for internal use only.

I would like to set the mirror to do write queries on the database which is hosted outside the network.
Best would be to set the mirror to do write queries both on its local DB and on the one outside the network.

Any suggestion?

I'm also wondering if there are any articles about developing **distributed** / **redundant** / **decentralized** applications with Django.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [multiple database documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) shows you how to set up two databases and how to [select a database for saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) which is what write operations do.